# skrollr mobile clicking on item returns error

Tags: javascript, android, ipad, mobile, compatibility

I am using the skrollr plugin for parallax https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr. I know it works fine on iPad 3 and iPhone 4S with version 6.1.3.

However, on an iPad 2 version 5.1.1 and several various Android devices, I have run into an issue where if I attempt to click on any link...or really anything at all...I get a message that says:

"JavaScript:Error undefined TypeError:'undefined' is not a function".

I isolated the issue to skrollr.js about line 649 initialElement.click();. If I remove that call, then the error no longer happens...except obviously I still can't click on anything.

Also, I know for sure that this is an error in the plugin itself because I tried clicking on things in the skrollr demo and get the same error http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/.

Has anyone come upon a solution for this? I haven't seen it posted anywhere. Also I've already tried alternatives such as:

```
initialElement.mousedown('click');
initialElement.trigger('click');
initialElement.bind('click');
initialElement.live('click');
initialElement.delegate('click');
```

and all give the same exact error.

I find it strange that it doesn't occur in all devices, and the rest of the plugin seems to be working...so it's not an issue on where I'm importing it...heck even everything else attached to initialElement seems to be okay.

Any ideas?

Once again, I would give you a link to my site but can't due to disclosure agreement. But if you need snippets of code let me know.

Thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: related https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/263

Comment: Hmm, so still no fix I presume?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give this a shot at line 644 - https://gist.github.com/JustinWUP/6032497

Answer (score 0):

Changing the following on skrollr.js worked for me. [Added $() around the 'initialElement']

```
if(distance2 < 49) {
    //It was a tap, click the element.
    //initialElement.focus();
    //initialElement.click();

    $(initialElement).focus();
    $(initialElement).click();
    return;
}
```